# SESSSION still work afterclosing tabs

Tags: php, mysql, session

i create php files that check user login in. If the user and password is correct, user can visit the catalog page. However there are some problems with the session. After reopening browser it still display the hidden data. I know the session will be closed when i close the browser but this case seems weird. This is the login form:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <?php

    $LabelLogin=array("login"=>"login",
                        "password"=>"password",
                        );
    echo "<h1> Login and Register Page </h1>";
    echo "<form action='CheckLoginDetail.php' method=POST>";
                    foreach($LabelLogin as $keys =>$values)
                    {
                        if($keys=='password')
                        {
                            echo "$values <input type='password' name='$keys' /><br/>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "$values <input type='text' name='$keys' /><br/>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<input type='submit'  value='submit' />";
    echo "<br/>click <a href='register.php'>here<a/> to register if you don't have an accout <br/>";                
    echo "</form>";
    ?>
    </body>
```

2nd CheckLoginDetail.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.inc");
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die ("can't connect to server");
$labels=array("login"=>"login",
                "password"=>"password");

foreach($_POST as $keys =>$values)
{
    if(empty($values))
    {
        $empty_values[]=$keys;
    }
    elseif(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/",$values))
    {
        $invalid_values[]=$keys;
    }
    else
    {
        $data[$keys]=$values;
    }
}
if(@sizeof($empty_values)>0 or @sizeof($invalid_values)>0)
{
    if(@sizeof($empty_values)>0)
    {
        echo "login name or password or both can not be empty !";
    }
    if(@sizeof($invalid_values)>0)
    {
        echo "values contain invalid characters";
    }
    include("FrontPage.php");
    exit();
}
else
{
    foreach($data as $keys =>$values)
    {
        $clean_data[$keys]=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,strip_tags(trim($values)));
    }

    $query="SELECT LoginName and Password FROM yugimemberinfo WHERE LoginName='";
    foreach($clean_data as $keys =>$values)
    {
        if($keys=="login")
        {
            $query.="$values'";
        }
        if($keys=="password")
        {
            $values=md5($values);
            $query.=" AND Password='$values'";
        }
    }



    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can't execute query ".mysqli_error($connect));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    {
        echo "login fail";
        include("FrontPage.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['access']="yes";
        echo "login succesfully !<br/>";
        echo "Here are two options for you :<br/>";
        echo "<ul>
                    <li><a href='ShowCatalog.php'>Go to Card Catalog</a></li>
                    <li><a href='search_form.php'>Searching for your cards</a></li>
                </ul>";

        $query_insert="INSERT INTO yugimember (LoginName,LoginTime) VALUES(";
        foreach($clean_data as $keys =>$values)
        {
        //echo "$keys =>$values<br/>";
            if($keys=="login")
            {
                $query_insert.="'$values',";
            }
        }
        //insert login name and time to yugimember
        $query_insert.="'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query_insert) or die ("can't execute query line 62");
    }
}
?>
```

if users login successfully, they can lick to the link that take them to another site called "ShowCatalog.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.inc");
$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die ("can't connect to server");
if(@$_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')
{
    include("FrontPage.php");
    exit();
}
$query="SELECT * FROM dragon ";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die("can't execute query");

echo "<hr/>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    echo $type."<br/>";
    echo $CardName."<br/>";
    echo $atk." \ ".$def."<br/>";
    echo $Description;
    echo "<br/>".$picture."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='../dragon/{$picture}'><img src='../dragon/{$picture}'  height='300' width='300'></a>";
    echo "<hr/>";


}


?>
```

I make the ShowCatalog.php only display data for user logining in. However when i login in and close the browser then reopen it the ShowCatalog.php the data is stilled appear.

Comment: You really need to stop using all those `@` symbols to squelch errors. It'll come back to bite you

Comment: Firefox does not throw away session cookies on close, is that the browser you are checking this in? You can get it to do so, but configuring it not to save your tabs on closing.

Comment: Iam using chrome is it similar to FF ?

Comment: Please try to create small example pieces of code which reproduce your problem, rather than pasting in large chunks of your application. Not only does it make it easier for others to understand and help you, the exercise of producing such an example may help you understand the problem better yourself.

Comment: sorry everyone ! my problem is when I close one tab on the browser  session still works, but when close the whole browser session stop work. Is that session still work after tab was closed ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but when you do this :

```
if(@$_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')
```

If the session does not exist (because you closed your browser), maybe it will bypass this condition.

Try :

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['access']) | $_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')
```

Comment: This `if (!isset($_SESSION['access']) | $_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')` is missing a `|` Change to `if (!isset($_SESSION['access']) || $_SESSION['access'] != 'yes')` in your answer.

Comment: @user3228228 See my comment above. --^

Comment: Then you need to create a logout page with `session_destroy();` inside it. @user3228228